# md-list ( angular-material design 2.0 ) - subcomponents should be on one line

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a this component template, each component is put on a seperate line ... i want all the component to be on one line.

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let md of memberDeclartions">
    <span md-line>
       <app-vehicle-type [selectedValue]="md.vehicleTypeValue">      
      </app-vehicle-type>

      <app-tyre-category [selectedValue]="md.tyreTypeValue">

      </app-tyre-category>
    </span>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'r nested component return each a `<p>` html tag. it is normal you've got two line. Maybe return something like this:

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let md of memberDeclartions">
    <p md-line>
       <app-vehicle-type [selectedValue]="md.vehicleTypeValue"></app-vehicle-type>
       <app-tyre-category [selectedValue]="md.tyreTypeValue"></app-tyre-category>
    </p>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

And app-vehicle-type, app-tyre-category components just return a string value without `<p>` html balise.